# @RequestMapping annotation not allowed on @FeignClient interfaces

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud-feign, request-mapping

I'm having trouble with this! As I've been reading, it happens because it's no longer accepted. But how can I solved it?
This is the code I've been trying to map.

```
@FeignClient(name = "product-service")
@RequestMapping("api/products/")
public interface ProductClient {

    @GetMapping("/{id}")
    ResponseEntity<Product> getProduct(@PathVariable("id") Long id);

    @GetMapping("/{id}/stock")
    ResponseEntity<Product> updateStockProduct(@PathVariable("id") Long id,@RequestParam(name = "quantity", required = true) Integer quantity);
}
```

Thanks in advance for any suggestion or solution!

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can use the `path` attribute of `@FeignClient` to define the path prefix to be added to all the APIs. The documentation is [here](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/org.springframework.cloud/spring-cloud-openfeign-core/latest/org/springframework/cloud/openfeign/FeignClient.html).

So your Feign client interface would look like

```
@FeignClient(name = "product-service", path = "/api/products")
public interface ProductClient {

    @GetMapping("/{id}")
    ResponseEntity<Product> getProduct(@PathVariable("id") Long id);

    @GetMapping("/{id}/stock")
    ResponseEntity<Product> updateStockProduct(@PathVariable("id") Long id,@RequestParam(name = "quantity", required = true) Integer quantity);
}
```